# Proof that an integral is convergent

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, riemann-integration

Prove that $$\int_0^∞ \frac{\sin(2x)}{x+2}\;dx$$ is a convergent integral.

Should I prove this by trying to show that it is bounded and monotone or should I use another proof? Any help please?

Comment: *"Should I prove this by trying to show that it is bounded and monotone"* : Good luck ;-) But you can try integration by part.

Answer (score 3):

Following Surb's suggestion, your integral is $$\left[-\frac12\frac{\cos 2x}{x+2}\right]_0^\infty-\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos 2x dx}{(x+2)^2}.$$The surface term is $\frac14$, while the integral is bounded between $\pm\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{(x+2)^2}=\pm\frac12$.

Comment: what do u mean by surface term?

Comment: @souadbouchahine The $[uv]_a^b$ part, in this case $\left[-\frac12\frac{\cos 2x}{x+2}\right]_0^\infty$. It's mostly a physicist's term.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n\in\Bbb Z_{\ge 0}$. Then
$$\begin{align}\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\frac{\sin(2t)}{t+2}dt&=\left|\int_{n\pi}^{(n+0.5)\pi}\frac{\sin(2t)}{t+2}dt\right|-\left|\int_{(n+0.5)\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\frac{\sin(2t)}{t+2}dt\right|\\
&\le\frac1{n\pi+2}-\frac{\left|\int_{(n+0.5)\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\sin(2t)dt\right|}{(n+1)\pi+2}\\
&=\frac1{n\pi+2}-\frac1{(n+1)\pi+2}
\end{align}$$
Now,
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(2t)}{t+2}dt\le\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac1{n\pi+2}-\frac1{(n+1)\pi+2}\right)=\frac12$$

Comment: You really make more complicated than it is ! (-1)

Comment: @Surb But the technique is very useful, so that's a +1 for me.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(2x)}{x+2}dx\le\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(2x)}{x}dx$$
and this integral can be solved by letting:
$$I(a)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(ax)}{x}dx$$
and using Feynman's trick.